# FBFriendPickerViewController not showing all friends

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using FBFriendPickerViewController to display a list of friends to invite in my iOS app.

It is only showing the list of friends that have the app installed. Why is this?

I'm also interacting with the Facebook sdk directly in my app, for using the Graph API. Could this be interfering? I'm opening a session for that with permissions: public_profile, user_friends friends_games_activity, publish_actions.

The app is in development mode on Facebook developer centre.

Here is my code for showing picker:

```
FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController =
[[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";

// Load the friend data
[friendPickerController loadData];
// Show the picker modally
[friendPickerController presentModallyFromViewController:self animated:YES handler:nil];
```

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From API Version v2.0 : Friend list only returns friends who also use your app. Check [Facebook Platform Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Comment: ok thanks. But then what is the recommended way for users to invite other people to the app? I've seen lots of other apps show a list of Facebook friends to send invites to.

Comment: If app is in game category then only you will get inevitable friend list.